# Change the size of a GroupBox

Tags: c++, qt

I am new in Qt and C ++, I have a code and I want to change it, when I open the file .ui  i find a ***GroupBox*** , I tried to change its size in the interface but it does not work, I tried to change it in the code but I can't find it, is that normal that it is in the interface and not in the code? and how to change it if it does, I expect your help and thank you.

Comment: Please, add some code

Comment: Use the `ui` variable to access objects you added in the designer.

Comment: DYangu, the code is very long, 500 lines (only mainwindow.cpp)

Comment: Then add a [MCVE]. Who knows, in the process of creating one, you might even figure out the answer for yourself!

Comment: Cody Gray, I tried but I found nothing I am new in Qt and I find it illogical tha the GroupBow is in the interface and not the code, Thuga gave me the solution, but I always ask the question why there is nothing in code about the GroupBox

Comment: There is, it is in the `ui_myclassname.h` file. This is an auto-generated file generated by the `uic`. Read [this documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) to understand how it works better.

Comment: Yes i find it, <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">, good

Comment: No, that's a different  file. That is the `myclassname.ui` file. That is an XML file generated by the designer.

Comment: Ok, I think I can't open the file ui_myclassname.h ? it because i dont find it in the folder. At least now it's clear.

Comment: @all.west you should find that file in the shadowed build directory. Anyway I am pretty sure you could not resize the QComboBox because it is packed into a layout. (You should be able to change the widgets minimal or maximal size, which worked for me, but not using mouse.)

Answer (score 0):

i use that code and it work:

```
ui->groupBox->setMinimumSize(QSize(0,0));
ui->groupBox->setMaximumSize(QSize(10000,10000));
ui->groupBox->setGeometry(9,707,810,450);
```

Comment: This code does nothing if the group box is in a layout. Setting the minimum/maximum size seems pointless as well.